# asp.net Nhibernate session managment

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, session, singleton

I implement standart scenario in asp.net session per reqest.
My asp.net module:

```
public class NHibernateSessionModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += context_EndRequest;
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var session = SessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        session.BeginTransaction();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);

    }

    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
        if (session != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
                    session.Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                session.Transaction.Rollback();
                throw new ApplicationException("Error committing database transaction", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Close();
            }
        }
        CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionManager.SessionFactory);
    }
}
```

My sessionManager is thread-safe singletone:

```
public class SessionManager
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return Instance.sessionFactory; }
    }
    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return Instance.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
    }
    public static ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(Instance.GetSessionFactory()))
                return null;
            return Instance.GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();
        }
    }


    public static SessionManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return NestedSessionManager.sessionManager;
        }
    }
    private SessionManager()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    class NestedSessionManager
    {
        internal static readonly SessionManager sessionManager =
            new SessionManager();
    }
}
```

The main idea open session in begin of request and then use session through `SessionManager.CurrentSession;`

Session is stored in configured context:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
```

My repository:

```
public class RepositoryNew<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IDisposable
{
    public RepositoryNew()
    {
        if (NHibernateSession == null)
            //Start session for not web version
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //flush session for not web version
    }

    protected override sealed ISession NHibernateSession
    {
        get
        {
            return SessionManager.CurrentSession; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    var repo = new RepositoryNew<Client>()
    clients = repo.GetAll();
}
```

By some reason this repository doesn't use opened session in module.

```
CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(Instance.GetSessionFactory())
```

returns false, so my code starts second session in request.
At debugger I see that I have instantieted my SessionManager twice.
My be I have two different ISesssion factories.
I haven't ideas yet what's wrong. I have spent on it a lot of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was strange error. When I remove link to SessionManager from my project, it starts work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another thing open session in Http Begin Request because every http request will open new session like request static image you must change this strategy to eliminate this unnecessary  session in every Http request you can read this blog and change your strategy http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx